# Change Action When Push Notification Swiped

Tags: objective-c, swift, apple-push-notifications

Is there a way to change the action when a user swipes on a push notification from your app? For example, a push notification that shows the text "Check out our new app!", then if the user swipes launch the App Store to that app. Does anyone know if there is a way to do this? If yes, could you please do it in Swift preferably, if in Objective-C it's fine I should be able to convert it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No. Users can only tap on Notifications. Of course if you load your app you can create your own internal notification and apply this behaviour. With iOS 8.0 Apple introduced interactive notificaionts, which when swiped reveal buttons, you could assign these buttons to launch the app store ...

Comment: @CW0007007 oh yeah I forgot about these. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

When user swipes or opens application from top popup, then `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is called with push notification options.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if (launchOptions != nil) {
         // Launched from push notification
         NSDictionary *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
         // So check here if push notification says "Check out our new app!"
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/app/crosswords-classic/id653530195"]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the code, I will begin converting it now and let you know how I go :)

Comment: The code worked just took a while on making the if statement because it was throwing a strange error. Thanks again